# How do I check if there are changes in pip dependencies before updating and installing them?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-composer

Installing a package like this (or pointing to a requirements file) causes AF to trigger an environment update:

```
gcloud composer environments update myenv \
    --location us-central1 \
    --project myproj \
    --update-pypi-package "scipy>=0.13.3"
```

If I immediately run that command again I get an actual error:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.composer.environments.update) INVALID_ARGUMENT: No change in configuration. Must specify a change to configuration.software_configuration.pypi_dependencies.scipy
```

I have no way of knowing what is going to happen. I'll either trigger an environment update because their is a change in dependencies or get back an error.

How do I run a check against a requirements file and see if there are updates before actually installing updates?

On AF proper I have a bunch of options because I can just call pip: `pip list --outdated`, `pip install pip-check && pip-check`, `pip install pip-tools && pip-review`, etc.

On composer all I see is `gcloud composer environments list-packages`.

I also can't even experiment with doing something like installing `pip-tools` into my composer env and running these command because I am only allowed to run airflow cli subcommands: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/composer/environments/run